# Get Childproducts not visible individually in collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I have the following code to get my product collection:

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->setOrder('id', 'ASC');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addWebsiteFilter($this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getId());
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->_productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
$collection->setVisibility($this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('neq' => 'bundle'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('neq' => 'configurable'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('neq' => 'grouped'));
```

I need included in this collection all child products that are set to "Not visible individually" where the parents are enabled and set to visible. 
Currently when the product is set to not visible it does not show up.

Comment: you want visible and not visible both products?

Comment: Yes. But only those not visible where the parent product is visible and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `setVisibility()` function with below code.

```
$collection->setVisibility(null);
```

It should work

Comment: This returns a completely empty collection.